# Riemann integrability of a charactersitic function

Tags: continuity, lebesgue-measure, riemann-integration

If $A$ is an open subset of $(0,1),$ then $\chi_A$ is Riemann integrable on $[0,1].$

**My attempt:** Since $A$ is an open subset of $(0,1),$ we can write $A$ as countable union of disjoint open intervals in $(0,1).$ So, we have that $$A=\bigcup_{n=1}^{\infty}(a_n,b_n),$$ where $a_i,b_i \in (0,1), a_i<b_i,$ for all $i \in \mathbb{N}$ with $(a_m,b_m)\cap(a_n,b_n)=\varnothing$ whenever $m\ne n.$

Now, we have that $$\chi_A=\begin{cases}
1 & \text{ if } x\in A \\
0 & \text{ if } x\notin A \\
\end{cases}$$

> **Observation:** The set of points of discontinuity of the function $\chi_A$ is precisely given by $D=\{a_i,b_i:i\in \mathbb{N}\}.$

> **Theorem:** Suppose $a<b$ and $f:[a,b] \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ is a bounded function. Then $f$ is Riemann integrable if and only if $$|\{x \in [a,b]:f \text{ is not continuous at }x \}|=0,$$ where $|\cdot|$ is the outer measure.

We can clearly see that $|D|=0,$ since D is countable.

Hence, $\chi_A$ is Riemann integrable, from the theorem stated.

Is there any logical flaw in my proof?

Please let me know. Any comments on the proof is highly appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: What if $A$ is the complement of the Cantor set?

Comment: @TedShifrin Thank you very much for your interest in my question. I got your point.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your observation regarding points of dis-continuity is not correct. For a simple example, consider the characteristic function of $\bigcup_n (\frac 1 {2n}, \frac 1 {2n-1})$. This function is not continuous at $0$. You can have more complicated situations, but I just gave  a simlple example.

What is true is $D=\partial A$.

In fact, what you are trying to prove is false. If $C$ is a fat Cantor set in $[0,1]$ and $A$ is its complement, then  $\partial A=C$ which has positive measure, so characteristic function of $A$ is not Riemann integrable.

Comment: Thank you for your interest in my question @geetha290rkm. 

I understood your answer. But I am facing trouble seeing $\partial A=C. $ We know that the Fat Cantor set is closed and nowhere dense. This means that $\partial C= \bar{C}-C^{\circ}=C-\varnothing=C.$ How to see that $\partial A=C$ ?.

Comment: Boundary of  a set and boundary of its complement are always the same. @MathRookie2204

Comment: I got your point. Thanks for your time @geetha290krm.